# In X Rebirth 3.0 where can I trade (ore, nividium, crystals, etc.) during the campaign when PMC is super-pissed at me?

Tags: x-rebirth

Can someone please explain this to me:

I am in the campaign where I have to sell 300 units of food rations (which I did with my Container type ship), and I have 2 Fedhelms and 1 construction vessel.

My Fedhelms are really freaking rich with supplies, but because of my reputation with PMC, I can't seem to trade the goods (ore, nividium, crystals, etc.) ANYWHERE.

Does someone know where I can sell these goods? I've checked all of the metalworks yards (including the friendly ones) and every time I bring up the trade menu (SHFT+T) and I try to select ORE, it says that my reputation with PMC is too low (Even if I'm in DeVries).

Comment: There should be no friendly metalwork yards in Albion. Are you sure? What faction is it? In what version of game you started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no buyers for Crystals, Nvidium, Ore and Silicon in DeVries, and all stations that can buy them in Albion - are Plutarch stations.

If you want to trade resources with Albion, you can buy yourself Liquid mining ship and collect Plasma or Ions for sell for AE Cell Fabs.

If you have Bulk minig ship, then instead of Ore you can gather Ice in *Molten Archon* and sell it to Water Distillery in *Furnace Chamber*.

After you will deliver 300 Food Fations, later in plot:

> you will buld station for yourself that will consume Ore.